# Modularity of transcription factors

Tags: transcription, gene-regulation

I attended a seminar about neurogenesis that presented results for PAX6 as an important TF that contains 3 domains with very distinct patterns of downstream expression. The speaker ended up saying that PAX6 can be considered as 3 TFs in one protein, acting independently in different situations:

[Relative roles of the different Pax6 domains for pancreatic alpha cell development](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1471-213X-10-39)

Does anybody know of more examples like this?

Comment: interesting - I have heard of 'generic' transcription factors that act on many genes via common sequence motifs (the CCAAT-enhancer-binding-proteins, for instance), but not factors that actually have different motifs with different downstream effects. I'm also interested in this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [NF-κB](http://www.nf-kb.org) family of transcription factors is very modular, with different combinations having different effects. The active (nuclear, DNA-bound) TF is a dimer, composed variously of [RelA/p65](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELA), [RelB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELB), [c-rel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REL), [NFKB1/p50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nfkb1), and/or [NFKB2/p52](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFKB2) subunits. For example, the "canonical" p65/p50 dimer is activated in response to stimulants like [TNF-α](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumor_necrosis_factor-alpha) (tumor necrosis factor alpha, released in response to inflammatory signals like the presence of pathogens) and [LPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipopolysaccharide) (lipopolysaccharide from the cell walls of [Gram-negative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-negative) bacteria), while the RelB/p52 dimer plays an important role in the development of [B cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_cell) (the immune system component that produces antibodies). The [AP-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP-1_%28transcription_factor%29) transcription factor is also heterodimeric, containing proteins from the Jun, Fos, JDP, and ATF families, and there are numerous other examples of multimeric transcription factor complexes. [This recent article](http://www.nature.com/ni/journal/v13/n1/full/ni.2151.html) in Nature Immunology (disclaimer: I was not involved in that research, but my old lab did similar work) shows DNA sequence-specific binding by different NF-κB dimers.

Polymerism in general, and dimerism in particular, are quite common modes of transcriptional activation and regulation. The large number of ways in which a relatively small number of transcription factors can be combined allows for the exquisite control of genes, responding to a huge variety of cellular situations. Unfortunately, it also means that mutations in key, common components can result in transformation, unrestricted growth, and the generation of tumors.

Answer (score 4):

There was a paper published in Cell last year that has shown that the binding motif of a Hox transcription factor will change depending on whether there's a co-factor bound to the Hox.

> Slattery *et al.* (2011) [Cofactor Binding Evokes Latent Differences in DNA Binding Specificity between Hox Proteins](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cell.2011.10.053). *Cell*, **147**(6) 1270-1282. doi: 10.1016/j.cell.2011.10.053 ([pdf](http://rohslab.cmb.usc.edu/Papers/2011_Cell_latent_specificity.pdf))